# Weird port 9000 service, how do I find out what it is?

Tags: server

```
root@server:~# sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1548/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1370/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1421/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1349/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1301/main.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1226/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1421/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1263/memcached
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1548/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1370/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1235/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6082                :::*                    LISTEN      1349/varnishd
```

It closes with "main.conf)" I am a newbe so obviously screwed up somewhere in the configuration file, just not sure it was. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command

```
lsof  | grep "9000 (LISTEN)"
```

should give you the information which process/program uses the port.

If lsof is not already installed you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install lsof
```

Comment: I get this with lsof:  root@server:~# lsof  | grep "9000 (LISTEN)"
php5-fpm   1301     root    6u  IPv4         1547331763        0t0        TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)

Comment: I wanted why it has a closing bracket at the end [1301/main.conf)] and if it is causing any problem?

Comment: If you use `less /proc/1301/cmdline` you get the full commandline of how the process was started. It is probably just the way the command is trimmed for the output.

Comment: You are right. I get this: `php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/main.conf)`   Thanks!